# Best way to convert ShowS to String?

Tags: haskell

How to to prettify

```
(displayS $ renderPretty 0.8 80 $ _errDoc ei <> linebreak) ""
```

why I cant

```
show $ displayS $ renderPretty 0.8 80 $ _errDoc ei <> linebreak
```

Comment: You can't prettify it, it isn't ugly to begin with!

Comment: So give it empty string is normal behavior, im asking just because DList has function `toList dl = unDL dl []`

Comment: The canonical function to convert `ShowS` to `String` is `($ "")`. What more do you need?

Comment: @dfeuer love it, exactly what I needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `show $ displayS blah` because `ShowS` isn't an instance of `Show`. Recall that

```
type ShowS = String -> String
```

so if we wanted an instance of `Show` we would have to write:

```
instance Show (String -> String) where
    show f = ...
```

And now we have a bit of a problem. After all, the only thing we can do with the function `f`, really, is call it with `String` arguments. There's a couple choices that spring to mind readily, but they each have drawbacks:

1. Try to describe the behavior of `f` on every possible input. This isn't going to work very well -- there's infinitely many inputs. Reading and understanding the infinite output would take a longish time.
2. Don't bother calling `f` at all. Pick a single `String` to be the output of `show`, as in `show f = "<it's a function, lol>"`. This isn't terribly useful because it doesn't actually give you any information about `f`.
3. Call `f` with the distinguished string `""`. This isn't useful because there are lots of different functions that give the same output for that input, and you won't be able to distinguish between them. (Maybe it so happens that your library for cooking up `ShowS` values won't have that problem, but if we're going to have the instance it ought to work for values that come from anywhere, not just some tiny subset of the values!)

Because of these considerations, an instance of `Show` for functions is not included in the standard libraries, though approaches (1) and (2) are available for installation from Hackage.

Comment: I think this is a bit unfair. Sure, the type `String -> String` allows functions to inspect the argument, but the idea of the `ShowS` type is that it represents strings as difference lists, with the convention that the argument is the remaining string and not looked at. This might not be manifest on the type level, and limits of the Haskell type class system prevent `instance Show ShowS`, but for any “law-abiding” value of `ShowS`, approach 3 is sensible.

Comment: @bjornmelgaard You've already used it: `showsToString f = f ""`. It's so simple it's not even worth giving a name.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I would object to such an instance appearing in the standard libraries, for the reasons I listed. I would be much less hesitant to allow an instance if `ShowS` were an abstract type whose operations all respected the law (that there exists string `s` for which the function is extensionally equal to `(s++)`), but that isn't the world we live in.

Comment: @DanielWagner , dont like hand-made gratuitous functions) love dfeuer answer

Comment: I agree with that! We can’t have that instance in the world we live in, but there is an instance we would like to have, if we could.